# Kitchen Disposal placement

Tags: garbage-disposal, placement

I have a double sink with equal size basins. Which side should the garbage disposal go on? The dishwasher is on the right.

Answer (score 1):

## Personal Preference

This is purely personal preference.

If you are going to use the two sinks for different types of dishes (e.g., kosher = 1 for meat, 1 for dairy) then I would put the disposal on the one that is likely to get more use.

If you are going to use the two sinks for wash vs. rinse then put the disposal on the wash sink as it will get the most food residue.

The dishwasher hose is normally long enough to reach the extra foot or so to the farther sink, and should be connected to the disposal. Disposals normally have a knockout for easily connecting a dishwasher. Make sure the dishwasher output either has an air gap or a properly installed high hose loop.